# my python code has an error involvinf % calculator and I can't find it

Tags: python

first, I'd like to mention that I'm a total novice in the areas of programming and mathematics. Can somebody please explain me why the result isn't 0?

```
variable_1 = 360*2305567963945518424753102147331756070
variable_2 = variable_1/1
variable_3 = variable_2 % 360
```

result => 72.0

Comment: In my terminal the result is `0L`

Comment: in jupyter and python3.6 console, the result was 72.0. However, the answer was 0 in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need  the decimal module for convert scientific no to no

your first output of * is too big so it converts into scientific no

```
import decimal

variable_1 = 360*2305567963945518424753102147331756070
print variable_1

variable_1 = decimal.Decimal(variable_1)
print variable_1

variable_3 = variable_1 / 360
print variable_3
```

for % use long

```
variable_3 = long(variable_1) % 360
```

Comment: Now it says                                                                                                        
variable_3 = variable_1 % 360  ==> print (variable_3) ==>
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]

Comment: use long or int over   variable_3 = long(variable_1) %360

Comment: seems like long doesn't exist in 3.6. I found no error while handling large numbers in 2.7... guess I'll have to work with 2.7 instead